# Create bins dynamically?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, coldfusion

I have the project where user should enter number of bins. This number can range from 0 to 1000. If user for example picks 10, next step will be to check the highest value in the array. Array holds numeric values. Here is example:

```
<cfset myArray = [5,45.74,9,21,88.78,33.56,12]>
```

I need to find the highest value in the array. For example in array above the highest value is 88.78. We can round this value to 89. Then I divide highest value with the number of bins. Then I will be able to set width of the each bin. Example:

```
<!--- *** Get the highest value in an array. Based on the max value in the array we will now how many bins we need. *** --->
<cfset maxBinVal = Round(arrayMax(myArray))>

<!--- *** This value can be changed. Depends how many bins user wants. *** --->
<cfset numberOfBins = 10>

<!--- *** Divide highest value in the array with the number of bins. *** --->
<cfset binWidth = maxBinVal / numberOfBins>

<!--- *** Loop stops before hits the highest value. Increment for binWidth to include the highest value. *** --->
<cfset maxVal = maxBinVal + binWidth>
<cfset arrayOfBins = arrayNew(1)>

<cfloop from="#binWidth#" to="#maxVal#" step="#binWidth#" index="i">
    <cfset arrayAppend(arrayOfBins,#i#)>
</cfloop>

<cfloop array="#arrayOfBins#" index="key">
    <cfoutput>Bin Point: #key#<br></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Output:

```
Bin Point: 8.9
Bin Point: 17.8
Bin Point: 26.7
Bin Point: 35.6
Bin Point: 44.5
Bin Point: 53.4
Bin Point: 62.3
Bin Point: 71.2
Bin Point: 80.1
Bin Point: 89
```

After I created bins next step is to place each value from `myArray` in the correct bin/array. This is tricky and I'm not sure what is the best approach/solution for this problem. If number of bins is static/always the same this would be way easier. In this case I have to loop over `myArray` and check in which bin value belongs. Here is example:

```
<cfif 5 LTE 8.9>
  <cfset arrayAppend(array1, 5)>
<cfelseif 5 GT 8.9 AND 5 LTE 17.8>
  <cfset arrayAppend(array2, 5)>
<cfelseif ...>
```

and so on...

Basically I have to check in which range value belongs and then append that `value position in an array` (example 5 has position 1 in myArray, so I want to append 1) that stores values for that bin. There is a reason why I have to store position of the value instead of value itself. The biggest problem is to figure it out how this can work if user change bin number. For example if instead of 10, user pick 12. Then my if statement would be different. If anyone can provide any help that would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should base your bin sizes on the *difference* between the highest and lowest values. If you base it only on the highest value, then you will potentially end up with a whole bunch of empty bins.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use Modulo.Once you have the bin, you can hash it and use a map for O(1) lookup of the bin.

```
>>> getBin = lambda x: x - (x % 8.9)
>>> getBin(0)
0.0
>>> getBin(8.7)
0.0
>>> getBin(8.9)
8.9
>>> getBin(11)
8.9
>>> getBin(20)
17.8
>>> getBin(89.9)
89.0
>>>
```